# Pythonic way to create a new dataframe from each row of an existing dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Please recommend a pythonic way to create a new data frame from each row of an existing data frame.

The suggestion MUST take into account that the number of rows of the existing data frame is random, so the solution offered has to account for that. (For the sake of the example below the original data frame includes 3 rows, however, the actual number of rows in the original data frame will be random.) The columns  of the original data frame will remain unchanged.

Original dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
 
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(3,3), columns=['column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3'], index = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3'])
print(df)
```

output:

```
       column 1  column 2  column 3
row 1  0.972855 -0.179018  0.177614
row 2 -2.146628 -1.639054 -0.708013
row 3 -1.295298 -0.313462 -0.229140
```

Desired output AFTER the solution has been implemented (Three new data frame is created as below, preserving the original columns):

dataframe 1:

```
   column 1  column 2  column 3
row 1  0.972855 -0.179018  0.177614
```

dataframe 2:

```
    column 1  column 2  column 3
row 2 -2.146628 -1.639054 -0.708013
```

dataframe 3:

```
    column 1  column 2  column 3
row 3 -2.146628 -1.639054 -0.708013
```

I also would like to retain the ability to address the new data frames created, and manipulate the data within them.

I have tried to implement my own solution by using the .iterrows function and using dynamically created variables, but I would like to know what would be the recommended, most simple, and elegant way of solving the problem.

Comment: Do you mind adding a bit of context as to *why* you need to do this? It may help you to let us see if this is an XY problem or not - this type of solution is not particularly scalable as you've designed it.

Comment: "I have tried to implement my own solution by using the .iterrows function and using dynamically created variables, but I would like to know what would be the recommended, most simple, and elegant way of solving the problem." We can only tell you if there's something wrong with it, if you show it to us. We cannot tell you what is "recommended, most simple, and elegant", because subjective questions [don't fit here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). If you have working code that you want to improve, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi, yes. In the program an initial "set-up" dataframe is created based on user input. The rows of this set-up dataframe will then be used to create new datframes which will feed the data to different functions, which will manipulate the data in the newly created dataframes. (I would like to keep the data stored in the original "set-up" dataframe unchanged.)

Comment: Karl, I said I "tried" to implement my own solution. (I could not get it work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think the solution I found for the problem is the best one out of everything that was suggested, so I am going to share it here:

First, we going to iterate through the rows of the original database using a "for" loop and the ".itertuples()" function.
Within the loop, the data returned by the ".itertuples()" function is used to construct a new pandas database, which is then stored in a dictionary.
The dictionary key to store each newly created database is derived from the first element returned by the ".itertuples" function.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
 
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(3,3), columns=['column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3'], index = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3'])

row = df.itertuples()

my_dict = {}

for row in df.itertuples():
    my_dict[row[0]] = pd.DataFrame([list(row)[1:]], columns=['column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3'],
                                   index = [row[0]])

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'row 1':        column 1  column 2  column 3
row 1  2.083922  1.513993  0.861644, 'row 2':        column 1  column 2  column 3
row 2  0.988185 -0.685701  0.252542, 'row 3':        column 1  column 2  column 3
row 3 -0.526314 -1.481147 -1.789547}
```

This is the most straightforward solution I was able to find. Any opinion on the above, please? (If there is a better solution, I will change the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use groupby for this, with globals which will set the new dataframe name. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
 
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(3,3), columns=['column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3'], index = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3'])

count = 0
for (uniquerow), group in df.groupby(df.index):
    count+=1
    globals()['df' + str(count)] = group
```

where `df1-dfn` has now been created for the n number of rows in the original dataframe.

Comment: Would it be possible to avoid using globals to achieve the desired goal, and perhaps use dictionaries instead? I have been reading that using globals to dynamically create variables is possible, but not recommended as it can get messy later down the line.